# runtime winform designer for users

Tags: c#, winforms

We are trying to build a budget program. It is going to be a big project. We want to let users build their own WinForms and controls into it. Then do some databindings but that is the next step.

Is there way to build a "runtime form designer" in c# ? I am reading this [PAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/magazine/cc163871%28en-us%29.aspx). It says it is possible but It doesnt give enough information to start and finish the designer.

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds terrifying.

Comment: Of course there is, since you can add and remove controls programmatically. (It would take a lot of work however.) Could you specify what's causing you problems? Your question seems to be too broad to be answered reasonably.

Comment: You know you are creating a monster, don't you? You'll end up with some bastard cross between Sharepoint and Visual Studio's IDE.

Comment: my boss want to me create such a designer. I know it is huge but I have to do it somehow. My question is too broad, I know. But I dont how to start to build designer:) I am gooogling all day and I couldnt find a very good tutorail to start

Comment: do u have a year or so to do it? cus' if not, quit now

Comment: I would recommend that you look into [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/), or some other component library that has support for runtime customization. (Disclaimer: I don't work for DevExpress, but I'm a happy customer.)

Comment: Sounds like your boss thinks your customers are smart enough to build their own applications. As soon as you finish this project, you're out of work. Luckily you will never finish this, as it is mere impossible. Not in the first place because users aren't developers. - @Renan, don't forget DreamWeaver / FrontPage.

Comment: This can easily be done with WPF and MEF (to have these forms included in the application as compiled assemblies). winforms in general is very limited. Still, @CodeCaster is right, as soon as you finish this you're out of work. And users are not developers (unless they really are)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a short answer because I can't give you a full answer; that will require too much time...

Basically you need to create a form and a `ToolBox`, just like VS, and have the users Drag-and-Drop the controls. The Drag-and-Drop needs to be enabled and it's event handled. You also need in the drop event handler to get the mouse position on the `Form` and programmaticaly create a default control there.

Now, a lot of questions come to mind. Those will have to be addressed as they come, because I can't answer them all in less than a day.